# C# code taking more time to execute

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to C# and i was using Linq to do some operations on datatable in c#. My method is taking about 35 seconds to complete the processing. Can someone please suggest how to improve the performance?

Input DataTable to the method has 35 KPIs and each KPI will have 13 months data in it for each fiscal year and foreach country. So, dt will have 35*13 = 455 records per fiscal year. In any case there will be 2 fiscal years. So 455*2 = 900 records per country. So we are taking about number of records to be less than 1000 in input datatable

```
void NeedtoImprovePerformance(DataTable dt)
{
    DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
    dv.Sort = "Fiscal_Year ASC";
    dt = dv.ToTable();

    var kpilist = from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  orderby table.Field<int>("Sub_Service_Type_Id")
                  group table by new { kpiName = table["KpiName"] } into groupby
                  select new
                  {
                      value = groupby.Key,
                      columnvalues = groupby
                  };

    var uniqueCountry = from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        group table by new { country = table["CountryName"] } into groupby
                        select new
                        {
                            value = groupby.Key,
                            columnValues = groupby
                        };

    foreach (var kpi in kpilist)
    {
        var KpiValues = from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        where table.Field<string>("KpiName") == kpi.value.kpiName.ToString()
                        select table;

        foreach (var countryName in uniqueCountry)
        {
            var availablePeriods = from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                   where table.Field<string>("KpiName").ToString() == kpi.value.kpiName.ToString() &&
                                   table.Field<string>("CountryName").ToString() == countryName.value.country.ToString()
                                   select table.Field<int>("Period").ToString();

            if (availablePeriods.Count() < 13 && availablePeriods.Count() > 0)
            {
                for (int period = 5; period < 17; period++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    if (!availablePeriods.ToList().Contains(period.ToString()))
                    {
                        dr[1] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["KpiName"].ToString();
                        dr[2] = countryName.value.country.ToString();
                        dr[3] = (period).ToString();

                        var availableFiscalYear = from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                  where table.Field<int>("Period").ToString() == period.ToString()
                                                  select table.Field<string>("Fiscal_Year").ToString();
                        if (availableFiscalYear == null || availableFiscalYear.Count() == 0)
                        {
                            if (ddlFiscalYear.SelectedItem.Text == ddlFiscalYear.Items[ddlFiscalYear.Items.Count - 1].Text)
                            {
                                if (period > 10)
                                    dr[4] = ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue.ToString();
                                else
                                    dr[4] = (Convert.ToInt32(ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue) - 1).ToString();

                                if (period == Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue) || period < Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue))
                                    dr[4] = (Convert.ToInt32(ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue) + 1).ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (period > Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue))
                                    dr[4] = (Convert.ToInt32(ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue) - 1).ToString();
                                else
                                {
                                    if (period == Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue))
                                        dr[4] = (Convert.ToInt32(ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue) + 1).ToString();
                                    else
                                        dr[4] = ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue.ToString();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dr[4] = availableFiscalYear.ToList()[0].ToString();
                        }

                        dr[5] = "";
                        dr[6] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["Frequency"].ToString();
                        dr[7] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["Sub_Service_Type_Id"].ToString();
                        dr[8] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["Service_Type_Id"].ToString();
                        dr[9] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["ServiceName"].ToString();
                        dr[10] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["OrderBy"];
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }

                    if (ddlMonth.SelectedValue == period.ToString())
                    {
                        var selectedPeriod = availablePeriods.Where(k => k == ddlMonth.SelectedValue).ToList();
                        if (selectedPeriod != null && selectedPeriod.Count == 1)
                        {
                            var PeriodFiscalYear = from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                   where table.Field<string>("KpiName").ToString() == kpi.value.kpiName.ToString() &&
                                                   table.Field<string>("CountryName").ToString() == countryName.value.country.ToString()
                                                   && table.Field<int>("Period") == period
                                                   select table.Field<string>("Fiscal_Year");
                            dr = null;
                            dr = dt.NewRow();
                            dr[1] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["KpiName"].ToString();
                            dr[2] = countryName.value.country.ToString();
                            dr[3] = (period).ToString();

                            var availableFiscalYear = from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                      where table.Field<int>("Period").ToString() == period.ToString() &&
                                                      table.Field<string>("Fiscal_Year").ToString() != PeriodFiscalYear.ToList()[0]
                                                      select table.Field<string>("Fiscal_Year").ToString();
                            if (availableFiscalYear == null || availableFiscalYear.Count() == 0)
                            {
                                if (ddlFiscalYear.SelectedItem.Text == ddlFiscalYear.Items[ddlFiscalYear.Items.Count - 1].Text)
                                {
                                    if (period > 10)
                                        dr[4] = ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue.ToString();
                                    else
                                        dr[4] = (Convert.ToInt32(ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue) - 1).ToString();

                                    if (period == Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue) || period < Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue))
                                        dr[4] = (Convert.ToInt32(ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue) + 1).ToString();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (period > Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue))
                                        dr[4] = (Convert.ToInt32(ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue) - 1).ToString();
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (period == Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue))
                                            dr[4] = (Convert.ToInt32(ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue) + 1).ToString();
                                        else
                                            dr[4] = ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue.ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dr[4] = availableFiscalYear.ToList()[0].ToString();
                            }

                            dr[5] = "";
                            dr[6] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["Frequency"].ToString();
                            dr[7] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["Sub_Service_Type_Id"].ToString();
                            dr[8] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["Service_Type_Id"].ToString();
                            dr[9] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["ServiceName"].ToString();
                            dr[10] = KpiValues.ToList()[0]["OrderBy"];
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dv = dt.DefaultView;
    dv.Sort = "KpiName ASC, Fiscal_Year ASC, Sub_Service_Type_Id ASC";
    dt = dv.ToTable();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There is only one thing to do in a situation like this, and that is to use a profiler to find out exactly what is eating the time.

Comment: Its a bit hard when you haven't said where the bottleneck is or what its supposed to do... although 3 nested for loops may not be the best thing (hard to tell) (never mind the linq queries)

Comment: foreach (var countryName in uniqueCountry) is taking almost 1 second for each kpi in kpilist. kpilist has about 35 KPIs and so it is taking about 35 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There are many performance issues in that code sample. Some improvements:

1. Move `dt.AsEnumerable()` outside both loops like `var table = dt.AsEnumerable()` and using that instead
2. Move the `.ToList()` on `KpiValues` to the first foreach and use the resulting list
3. You are also querying the `availablePeriods` multiple times (2x `.Count()`, 2x `.ToList()`), you can improve that by calling `.ToList()` once and use that list on all locations.

In general: try to query as little as possible. The variables `KpiValues` and `availablePeriods` are not lists of things but query definitions. Everytime you get some data out of that it will execute the query to get the data instead of reusing previous results what you might have expected.